# Jetpack compose dynamic snackbar position

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a view-based application with many screens with different elements at the bottom of the screen and a requirement that `There are certain important elements at the bottom of the screen, never occlude them with a snackbar`. At any point in time those VIP elements may be visible or gone and appear in virtually any combination.

In order to meet the requirement I am using a simple approach, any view in the hierarchy can be tagged with a special tag `dont-show-snackbars-over-me`, and a common utility `showSnackbar()` function that collects all visible views with the mentioned tag, finds the top-most by Y axis and uses this view as the `anchor view` for the snackbar.

How would one do the same thing with snackbars in jetpack compose? The goal is to avoid any complex if-else-ladders logic, just a common way to tell in any compose function `dont-show-snackbars-over-me` and everything should just work.

I figure using `CompositionLocal` for marking the compose functions as `dont-show-snackbars-over-me`, but further I'm stuck, what exactly to put to the CompositionLocal and how to use this information to place the snackbar.

Any ideas?